# relationships in django 2 models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to define a relationship between `Book` and `Member` through `Borrow` in `models.py`

[ER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QaVy.png)

But I don't know how to define the `Borrow` relationship.
In the `Borrow` table it must be determined which books have been borrowed by who and which books have been returned on which date. Should I use another table for this date field?

## `models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

class CategoryType(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="عنوان", max_length=128)
    number_of_copy = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    writer = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    B_category = models.ForeignKey(CategoryType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["B_category"]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Borrow(models.Model):
    borrowed_from_date = models.DateField(_("borrow Date"), default=0)
    borrowed_to_date = models.DateField(_("return Date"), default=3)
    actual_return_date = models.DateField()
    borrowed_by = models.ForeignKey(member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id


class Member(AbstractUser):
   pass
```

I think in the `Member` class I should have a field containing `borrow_id`, but how?

Comment: Are you trying to make the `Borrow` table have an array of `books` or are you trying to create one `Borrow` record per book borrowed?

Comment: @Rigo :to make the Borrow table have an array of books

Comment: I think @user3080294's solution is a better approach than having an array of books.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you need to use a `ManyToMany` relationship with a `through` model (this way you can store extra information for every row of the `Borrow` model)

```
...

class Borrow(models.Model):
    borrowed_from_date = models.DateField(_("borrow Date"), default=0)
    borrowed_to_date = models.DateField(_("return Date"), default=3)
    actual_return_date = models.DateField()
    borrowed_by = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id

...
class Member(AbstractUser):
    borrowed_books = models.ManyToManyField(Book, through='Borrow')
```

Maybe this link (https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) could clarify it more.